# Using AND and OR on speech recognition result in my app

Tags: java, android, operators, speech-recognition

I am using google speech recognition API for my game and I want to count the number of times the user says "my forced" but don't count if the user says "my unforced"

For that I use this code:

```
//save the result from speech recognition
public void onResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "on results");
        ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String s = "";
        for (String result:matches)
            s += result + "\n";

        Log.i(TAG,"results: "+ matches.get(0));
        Log.i("what I said",s);
        gamePoints(s);
  }

//count "s" if it adheres to the condition
public void gamePoints(String s) {
   if ((s.contains("my")) &&
      (s.contains("fau")||s.contains("for")) && 
      (!s.contains("on")||!s.contains("un"))){
            count++;
   }
}
```

my speech result in the log was that:

my unforced
Mayan Forest
my enforced
myON forced
my own forced

If my code was ok it would not had count that sentence, but from some reason it did.

the logic of my condition is: to count every time the letters in "s" contain ("my") and ("for" or "fau") as long "s" doesn't contain ("on" or "un")

Can someone explain me please what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question and spell out the full logic.

Comment: I edited it and added more information

Comment: What would be helpful would be if you clearly explain the logic behind what you expect to match and to not match.  Give plenty of examples.

Comment: I added that. I want to count "my forced" but dont count "my unforced"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `if` statement I would write based on your updated logic:

```
if ( s.contains("my") &&
    (s.contains("fau") || s.contains("for")) &&
    (!s.contains("on") && !s.contains("un")) ) {
    count++;
}
```

Note that the ORed terms are in parenthesis.  Also, based on DeMorgan's laws, the opposite of `doesn't contain ("on" or "un")` is `doesn't contain "on" AND doesn't contain "un"`.